# Pandas replacing the number only for the columns that contains number

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe that has more than 100 columns. but here I am trying to replacing the number all across the dataframe whose column contains the number (Int/float/any formate of number).

I know how to take care column seperately, but i am looking for some smart code that efficiently replacing the value to -5 if Value <= 0 and 111 if value > 50.

Below is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Avery Bradley', 'Jae Crowder', 'John Holland', 'R.J. Hunter'],
 'Team': ['Boston Celtics',
  'Boston Celtics',
  'Boston Celtics',
  'Boston Celtics'],
 'Number1': [0.0, 999.0, -30.0, 28.0],
 'Number2': [1000, 500, -10, 25],
 'Position': ['PG', 'SF', 'SG', 'SG']})

#df["Number1"].values[df["Number1"] > 50] = 999
#df["Number1"].values[df["Number1"] < 0]  = -5

df[ df > 50 ] = 888
df[ df < 0  ] = -5
```

Comment: pandas clip probably.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`select_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for multiple conditions here:

```
m = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
df[m.columns] = np.select([m>50,m<0],[888,-5],m)
```

---

```
print(df)
            Name            Team  Number1  Number2 Position
0  Avery Bradley  Boston Celtics      0.0    888.0       PG
1    Jae Crowder  Boston Celtics    888.0    888.0       SF
2   John Holland  Boston Celtics     -5.0     -5.0       SG
3    R.J. Hunter  Boston Celtics     28.0     25.0       SG
```

Comment: @jezrael you mean dtypes? yes both columns will be transformed to float here since we are using numpy.

Comment: @OO7 Glad it helped you , A quick note if it helps:  if you are specific about the dtypes , you can always store the original df dtypes as `s = df.dtypes` before doing the modification as a first step  , and then assign that dtype as `df = df.astype(s)` after the modification as the last step. Since np select gives you a quick way to assign values based on multiple conditions i went for the same but a np array will have just a single dtype.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
c = df.select_dtypes(np.number).columns
df[c] = df[c].mask(df[c] > 50, 888)
df[c] = df[c].mask(df[c] < 0, -5)
print (df)
            Name            Team  Number1  Number2 Position
0  Avery Bradley  Boston Celtics      0.0      888       PG
1    Jae Crowder  Boston Celtics    888.0      888       SF
2   John Holland  Boston Celtics     -5.0       -5       SG
3    R.J. Hunter  Boston Celtics     28.0       25       SG
```